# Angular : ngFor data items and display custom message if empty

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular6, angular2-template

I am looping my data list and displaying in the view , as spans tags :

```
<span  *ngFor="let d of myData; last as isLast"> 
{{d.name}} 
<span *ngIf="!isLast">,</span>
</span>
```

As you can see , I am adding a comma '**, betewen items values

this looks like this ::

```
AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,
```

But it happens **that my data would be empty** : so i want to display some **custom string** instead :  `"NO ITEMS"`

i wante to handle that in the html part , with pipes

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap the list in another container and display it only if the data array is not empty, else - display another custom content, e.g.:

```
<div>
    <div *ngIf="myData.length">...// existing list of spans</div>
    <div *ngIf="!myData.length">NO DATA</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [ngIf ... else](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else) construct to display an alternative template when the array contains no data. To avoid adding an HTML container around the outer `span` element, wrap it inside an `ng-container` (which is not rendered in the HTML output):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myData.length > 0; else noItems">
  <span *ngFor="let d of myData; last as isLast">
    {{d.name}} 
    <span *ngIf="!isLast">,</span>
  </span>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #noItems>
  NO ITEMS!!!
</ng-template>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwjmig) for a demo.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution using pipes

The idea is to add another element to `myData` if it is empty else leave it untouched like this:

Create a new file `data.pipe.ts` add the following content in it:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({
    pure: false, // We need to update if it change, you are free to remove if you don't want this behaviour
    name: 'appData'
})
export class DataPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(data: any) { // Here data should be an array.
        if (data.length === 0) {
            return ['NO DATA'];
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your `AppModule` or in any module(in which you want to add it) in the declaration array add the `DataPipe` (Don't forget to add the import) and now in your template file:

```
<span  *ngFor="let d of myData | appData; last as isLast"> 
{{d.name}} 
<span *ngIf="!isLast">,</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pipes for this is unnecessary as a single ngIf and ngElse should solve it or even the double ngIf conditioning with opposite conditions should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own pipe that evaluates the list and responds to one by default in case the original list is empty. For example:

Define the pipe as follows:

```
@Pipe({name: 'empty'})
export class EmptyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any[], emptyText: string = 'NO ITEMS'): any {
    return value && value.length > 0? value : [{name: emptyText}];
  }
}
```

Add the pipe to the declaration of your module:

```
NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, EmptyPipe ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally use the pipe in the *ngFor as follows:

```
<span  *ngFor="let d of myData | empty; last as isLast"> 
{{d.name}} 
<span *ngIf="!isLast">,</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs it, I did it without the wrapper container

```
<span *ngFor="let data of myData || []">{{ data.name }}</span>  
<span *ngIf="myData?.length == 0">NO ITEMS</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span  *ngFor="let d of myData | appData;"> 
    {{d.name}} 
    <span *ngIf="(myData | appData).length==0">
        Your custom message
    </span>
</span>
```

Try this.